# not able to add value in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to add some value in firebase with react-native

it works fine in my android emulator but firebase didn't get the data

Here is my dependencies

"firebase": "^3.6.9",
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "0.41.2",

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
class FoodApp extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

  var config =  {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC-7eB-K4LxCvnBVVmRrKZWaN8zgMAOHgc",
    authDomain: "chatapp-1d56d.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://chatapp-1d56d.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "chatapp-1d56d.appspot.com"

  };
  Firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var database = Firebase.database();
  database.ref().set({
    title:'test',
    author:'tomlishan'
  });

 }
   render() {
    return (
    <Text>
      hi
    </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my database rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `messagingSenderId` in your config. Try adding one. Here is a reference [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)
In general the DB must know from where the query is coming.

Hope this fixes your problem.